# Difference between 2 variables with diagonal line means equal plot called?

Tags: data-visualization

I make this kind of scatterplot a lot and was curious if it had a proper name. The diagonal line is when the two variables have the same value. The observations that occur above the line have a greater value in the y axis and below the line have a greater value in the x-axis.

The vertical and horizontal distance from the line represents the absolute difference between the groups. And the diagonal distance half of that difference. Generally, the idea is further from the line greater the difference between the variables.

The plots makes the most sense when both variables have the same scale.

[image]

Comment: This is called a "scatterplot."

Comment: I am curious if there is a particular name. For example, qq-plots and pp-plots have a name which have the same idea of a diagonal line indicates similarity.

Comment: "Scatter plot with a 1:1 line" ?

Comment: Generically it can be called a "reference line."

Comment: Sometimes called a calibration plot in other contexts, but here the purpose is not, I guess, calibration at all but just comparison.  If there were a different name for every slightly different plot, we would be tripping over terminology interminably.  More interestingly, a plot of difference versus mean is often helpful;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a diagonal line can appropriately be called a reference line as mentioned by whuber